# css media queries - how to target only ios or android devices?

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, media

I have a mobile website.
I optimize it for android, for example

```
    @media only screen 
and (max-height : 1280px) {
    html {
        font-size: 18pt;
        }
    }

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait)
and (max-height : 452px) {
    html {
        font-size: 15pt;
        }
    }
```

but on ios it looks really bad. Can I use 2 sets of media queries, one for android and one for ios?
right now I can't make it work for both of them.

Please show me a media query for android devices and a media query for ios devices.

Comment: perhaps you can do a google search for [android and ios media query css](https://www.google.com/#q=android%20and%20ios%20media%20query%20css), and find [this](http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/) or [this](http://snipplr.com/view/67341/android-and-iphone--modern-css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```css
@media(orientation:landscape)

{
  html {
    font-size: 18pt;
  }
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  html {
    font-size: 15pt;
  }
}
```